# ServiceStack Authentication in standard MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack API residing in the "api" location of an MVC project. Alongside this API there are standard MVC controllers and views that call the ServiceStack services using  `HostContext.ResolveService<MyService>(HttpContext)`.

I have authentication set up using the ServiceStack `AuthenticateService`, calling `Authenticate(new Authenticate {...})` method then setting the FormsAuthentication cookie. I do not have FormsAuthentication itself enabled in web.config. Here's the auth setup in AppHost.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(Container container)
{
    var authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
        {
            new BasicAuthProvider(), 
            new CredentialsAuthProvider()
        })
    {
        HtmlRedirect = "/Login",
        MaxLoginAttempts = 5,
        IncludeAssignRoleServices = false
    };
    Plugins.Add(authFeature);

    Register<IUserAuthRepository>(new OrmLiteAuthRepository(Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>())
    {
        UseDistinctRoleTables = true
    });

    Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
}
```

Everything works great on the initial run of the app. Unauthenticated users get the login page, it logs them in, and I can pull session data like name and timezone. I access the session in the views to populate the menu with the following code:

```
@{
    var key = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey() ?? "";
    var sess = HostContext.Resolve<ICacheClient>().Get<AuthUserSession>(key).ConvertTo<CustomUserSession>();
}
Welcome @sess.FirstName @sess.LastName
```

However, after a period of time it looks like the session expires, and although the ServiceStack session I pull above shows `true` for `IsAuthenticated`, none of the other session data like first/last name and timezone is accessible.

Because the period of time I'm talking about is like 12 hours, my suspicion is that the session really *isn't* still authenticated. I tried enabling FormsAuthentication in web.config, but that screwed up the api endpoints, even when I exclude it in web.config under the `location` section.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's suspicious that `IsAuthenticated=true` but none of the other properties are populated given that a [ServiceStack session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack) is just a typed POCO serialized into the registered [Caching Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). I'd check the serialized value in the underlying caching provider to see if that's really the case. One thing that stands out is that you've specified in the AuthFeature that you're using `CustomUserSession` but you're instead trying to resolve it into `AuthUserSession`, you need to use the same typed session.

If you're using MVC with ServiceStack it's recommended to resolve the session using the official API's by [inheriting ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration) and resolving the ServiceStack Session in your Controllers with:

```
var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
```

Comment: In the controllers I do that. The problem is that the login menu I'm trying to populate with the user's name is in the `_Layout.cshtml` page and therefore can't be populated from the controller. I'll change the call to pull the `CustomUserSession` directly as opposed to converting it, but the properties in question (first/last name) don't exist in that custom session.

Comment: @Josh Does your [CustomUserSession have DataContract attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack)? Otherwise can't tell what the issue is, check what raw string value is serialized in the cache at the session key.

Comment: It does not...just added and will monitor to see if it happens again. Thanks, @mythz. FYI, paying SS customer here, so I really appreciate the quick help :)